# puppet resource with duplicate attributes fails instead of overwriting

Tags: puppet

If I have puppet resources with duplicate attributes, why does it fail instead of overwriting?

```
file { '/tmp/the_inlinetemplate.txt' :
       content => inline_template("What do you get if multiply 6 by 9 ? <%= 6 * 7 %> . \n")
       content => inline_template("My address <%= ipaddress %> \n")
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You just cannot define the same parameter twice. From documentation:

> A resource declaration is an expression that describes the desired state for a resource and tells Puppet to add it to the catalog

In your example it is impossible to decide which file content is desired:

```
"What do you get if multiply 6 by 9 ? <%= 6 * 7 %> . \n"
```

or

```
"My address <%= ipaddress %> \n"
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought about several different answers, but the bottom line is simply that that's how Puppet chooses to deal with the uncertainty in what you are asking it to do.  Rather than adopting an arbitrary rule to deal with the situation (why should it choose the last-appearing property binding instead of the first, or a random one?) it insists that you be clear and unambiguous up front.

This provides a degree of protection against performing unintended actions.  Although the content of file `/tmp/the_inlinetemplate.txt` in particular probably doesn't matter in the grand scheme of things, Puppet applies the same principle to *all* resource declarations, many of which are rather more consequential.